# Convert digits to ascii, then an int? c++

Tags: c++, char, ascii

If I have individual chars on a line, for example: 4356
How could I convert them to a final whole number?  So instead of '4' '3' '5' '6', it would be 4356.
So, I know I need to take the first digit and multiply it by 10 and add the next digit then multiply all that by 10 until I reach the last number. How can I write that in an efficient non-crashing way?

Comment: Part 2 of your question: Use a function like `atoi()` (ASCII-to-Integer) to convert to an `int`.

Comment: `atoi` can handle the first part too, actually, if the chars are part of a string.

Comment: What about reading each character at a time, then adding them together to get the final number?

Comment: Lookup `std::istringstream` and use the `operator >>` for integers.

Comment: How is it supposed to deal with invalid characters? `"12*A3%" -> 123 (int)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
char chars[NUM_OF_CHARS] = { '4','5','8'};
int value = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<NUM_OF_CHARS;i++)
    {   
        if(chars[i] >= '0' && chars[i] <= '9') {
            value*=10;
            value+=chars[i] - '0';
        }
    }
```

And if you have the chars in null-terminated string, use atoi() as guys in comments suggested.

Comment: My program reads through a line of symbols and digits, example: 34$%43%@.  It finds each digit and prints it on a line as 3443.  But it's not the actual number, just 4 different chars, so how could I convert each char to an int, then keep adding them together till the end of line?

Comment: See edited code above. Replace `chars` array with your supplied line.

Answer (score 0):

With C++ you can use `std::cin` to read into `char`, check if it is a digit, and then manipulate the total.

```
int total = 0;
char c;
while( std::cin >> c && c != '\n' )
{
   if( c >= '0' && c <= '9' )
       total = total * 10 + (c - 48);
}

std::cout << "Value: " << total << std::endl;
```

Comment: what if the input was something like: `123ff13'

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi According to the comment the OP made on Kissiel's answer: "My program reads through a line of symbols and digits, example: 34$%43%@. It finds each digit and prints it on a line as 3443. But it's not the actual number, just 4 different chars, so how could I convert each char to an int, then keep adding them together till the end of line?", it seems like this would produce the result he wanted: "12313"

Comment: my apologies I didn't notice that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read input in an object of type std::string and then use function `std::stoull` ( or `std::stoi` or some other function from this family of functions )

For example

```
std::string s;

std::cin >> s;

unsigned long long = stoull( s );
```

Or you can simply read into some integral object:)

For example if `in_file` is some input file stream then you can write

```
unsigned long long n;

while ( in_file >> n ) std::cout << n;
```

Or

```
std::vector<unsigned long long> v;
v.reserve( 100 );
unsigned long long n;

while ( in_file >> n ) v.push_back( n );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using `sringstream`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::string s ="1234";//or any number...
    //or: char s[] = "1234";
    std::stringstream strio;
    strio<<s;
    strio>>n;
    std::cout<<n<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```